# Avoiding trousers to get wet

Tags: clothing, comfort, water, bathroom

When using trousers in bathroom, the leg part of my trousers are always wet after touching the floor. How to use trousers in bathroom without wetting the trousers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best idea will be to remove your trousers, hang it on hooks of the bathroom and put it after use. But if that takes away some of your time, you can go for following idea:

- Fold the tip of your trouser as shown in the below picture before you enter bathroom and use. While going out of the bathroom, unfold them to normal and then you can find your trouser tips unwet.

[image]